# Mysql bidirectionnal replication

Tags: mysql

I'm a student and I would like to replicate in real time the entries in Table A and Table B.

table A (article_id, article_content) in database A

table B (id, article) in database B

I want them to have the same entries all the time.
If there is a new entry in table A, I want it to be added into table B in real time (with low latency) but I cannot do it straight away because the fields aren't the same.

So I thought about replicating both tables in each database

table A in database A replicated in table AB in database B
table B in database B replicated in table AB in database A

and then add some triggers to table AB to modify correctly table A and table B.

Is it a good solution ? thanks

Comment: I would suggest modifying one of the applications so that they are both writing to the same table. Alternatively you could replace one of the tables with a view of the other table. What MySQL version are you running and are both the databases on the same server? What are the table structures?

Comment: mysql 5.0.4 +, and the databases are not automatically in the same server.

Comment: I think you need to further explain your setup in order to get the best advice. Replication sounds like overkill to me. What are the traffic levels? What are the database / table structures? Are you able to use federated tables (use "SHOW ENGINES" to see if FEDERATED is available)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest a master db to write to and then set up slaves to clone master. Otherwise you will have a hell of a time managing keys/foreign keys.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not expert with the replication atm. I edited the post maybe it's easier to understand now

Answer (score 0):

Well for a start if the tables are different that's not replication....

If you go down the route you are proposing, bearing in mind triggers are part of a transaction.

DatabaseA has TableA and TableBCopy
DatabaseB has TableB and TableACopy

So TableA replicates to TableACopy and TableB replicates to TableBCopy
Trigger From TableBCopy modifies TableA, which replicates to TableACopy which triggers a change to TableB, which replicates to TableBCopy....
while
Trigger From TableACopy modifies TableB, which replicates to TableBCopy which triggers a change to TableA, which replicates to TableACopy...

Which bit of the above sounds like a good idea?

Even if you get it right, and don't end up recursive, sniff loudly near the implementation and it will fall over in a big way.

As @Ian Wood suggested, me thinks....